# iOS 7 : 'isa' is deprecated

Tags: ios7, xcode5, jsonkit

I get warning when I run my app in iOS7 "'isa' is deprecated", I don't have any idea how to fix this warning message. Please any one help on this.

```
array->isa      = _JKArrayClass;
```

Comment: I'd recommend getting rid of JSONKit from your project. It's, for one, not compatible with 64-bit architecture, because of the language hacks used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Include `<objc/runtime.h>`.

Replace everything like `array->isa = _JKArrayClass;` with `object_setClass(array, _JKArrayClass)`

And everything like `class = array.isa` with `class = object_getClass(array)`

Comment: And, also, please share your fork on GitHub?

Comment: I had this error twice, in one build. your fix works for one of them, but the other appears to be in a library, I can't edit or save that. How would I fix that one please ?  not sure where the lib came from.

Answer (score 15):

I figured I would share my solution for you Cocoapods users out there. (Please let me know in the comments if you have found a better solution)

I am using Cocoapods and for this reason I do not want to modify the source code of the libraries I am pulling in. The problem is caused by Cocoapods setting the "Direct usage of 'isa'" value to "Yes (treat as error)", thus causing all automated builds to fail.

I have fixed the problem by adding this to my Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

This way the direct usage of 'isa' will show up as warning but will not cause automated builds to fail.

But in arm64 iOS Device build(with Xcode 5.1.0) strangely CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = 'YES' option will not properly applied(treat as error). 
If you need to build, including arm64 just CLANG_WARN_DIRECT_OBJC_ISA_USAGE = 'NO' option can be used.

Comment: thanks, this works. tested in xcode Version 5.0.2 (5A3005) and mavericks 19.9.1

Comment: Unfortunately, my pod update fails applying this patch. There is no detail about the error: `LoadError - no such file to load...` I'm working with Xcode 5.1 and i0S 7.1. Do you have any idea about this ? Thanks

Comment: That error doesn't tell me much. If I remember correctly, the error was caused by JSONKit. If this error is caused by a pod, then this fix (I haven't tested it) should work. Otherwise, you should be able to fix it in your code. Have you been able to fix it?